# What brand is this vintage bicycle?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: Picture 1]

![It says 'T' and under it ''Made in Austria'' in the English language, which I find strange[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dewBB.jpg)

[image]

How do I identify this bicycle? I couldn't find online any manufacturer from Austria called merely 'T'.

Comment: There were a lot of department store 3 speeds that were made in the 50's and 60's in Austria. Sears sold 3 speeds that were made by Puch in Austria, but branded as a "Sears Bicycle". This is probably a department store 3 speed, I don't think the "T" is the manufacturer. It would be more helpful if you could tell us who the manufacturer of the 3 speed hub and other components were. Also, what's stamped on the bottom bracket?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your comment.I uploaded a few more photos. It says I think 'TWA' (Transatlantic World airlines?), and 'Made in austria'. I suspect it was a bicycle that lived most of its life in USA. Why would austrian manufacturer stamp it in English language? It was for export to USA apparently. I bought it in Berlin in a bad state and paid someone to refurbish it a bit. It has 3 speed but no identification on the hub of any sort. I tried to google around and found not much so Im just making stories up based on thin clues.

Comment: No, it's not a sears bike, I've been able to find a number of TWA bikes online, but from overseas: [1](http://www.gumtree.pl/cp-sprzedam-inne/poznan/kolarzowka-twa-made-in-austria-614214393),  [2](http://www.dublinbikeman.com/photogallery/DSCN2329.JPG), [3](http://www.dublinbikeman.com/photogallery/DSCN2227gg.JPG), [4](http://www.dublinbikeman.com/photogallery/DSCN3906d.JPG)

Comment: I would think that if it were branded for TWA airlines the badges would resemble TWA's logo a bit more.  [This image](http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/236x/81/50/16/81501664123a95830ed53a30b89defe6.jpg) shows several logos, and there is no great resemblance.  (However, a plausible reason for there being TWA airline bikes of about that style would be for transportation around airports, though one would expect a basket.)

Comment: They came thru http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage-bicycles-what-s-worth-appraisals-inquiries/982531-what-brand-its-worth.html

Comment: From bikeforums.net reply: T W A - Reviews & Brand Information - TRIUMPH-FAHRRADINDUSTRIE GESELLSCHAFT M.B.H. & CO KG 8580 KOFLACH, STEIERMARK , - Serial Number: 73465925